# radial progress bar to ionic v.2?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I need a radial progress bar Ionic. V.2, but found only for Ionic v.1 (https://github.com/tgarlanger/ion-radial-progress).

Has anyone done or figured out how to do it?

Comment: Did you happen to figure this out.

Comment: I am also looking for same :|

Comment: I ended up giving up, but I plan to come back one day and use our friend's solution @Danish Jamil

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it's too late. But, it might help someone else. I was looking for same kind of thing and found this. Worked like a charm! Follow the instructions on this link: https://github.com/crisbeto/angular-svg-round-progressbar and import the module like this =>

```
import { RoundProgressModule } from "angular-svg-round-progressbar/dist";

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RoundProgressModule
  ]
})
```

> Notice: import statement is the important part which I have demonstrated above. Copy the import statement from above, not from the link. Other instructions are very clear on that github page.